# Get Posted Data From Form

Tags: node.js

Here is a html form which posts:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Home Html Page</h1>
<a href="/Product/Index">Go To Product</a>
<hr/>
<form action="/Home/Index" method="POST" name="form1">
    Enter Text:
    <input type="text" id="txtInput"/>
    <button id="btnPost">Post Data</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is JavaScript code which should get posted data:

```
function Server(req, resp) {
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        var chunk = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            chunk += data;
        });
        req.on('end', function () {
            console.log(chunk + "<-Posted Data Test");
        });
    }'

    ...

    resp.write(...);
    resp.end();
}
```

Can you help me? I'm new in nodejs, so can you show me example?

Comment: That's pretty much the code I've got (which I'm not using, so I can't really comment on its value) what problem are you seeing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to specify a `name` on your `<input>` element like this:

```
<input name="txtInput" type="text" id="txtInput">
```

only those with `name` set get posted.

Example:

```
var http=require('http');
var util=require('util');
var querystring=require('querystring');

var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    if (req.method=='GET'){
        res.end('<form action="/Home/Index" method="POST" name="form1">Enter Text:<input name="txtInput" type="text" id="txtInput"/><button type="submit" id="btnPost">Post Data</button></form></body></html>');
    }else{

        var chunk = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            chunk += data;
        });
        req.on('end', function () {
            console.log(chunk + "<-Posted Data Test");

            res.end(util.inspect(querystring.parse(chunk)));
        });

    }
}).listen(8080);
```

To parse the formdata just use [querystring.parse(str, [sep], [eq])](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq) (like in the example above)

Example:

```
querystring.parse('foo=bar&baz=qux&baz=quux&corge')
// returns
{ foo: 'bar', baz: ['qux', 'quux'], corge: '' }
```